# Resizing div based on a rendered div and available viewport

Tags: html, autoresize

I am a Doctor working on a small departmental website. I am using a two-column design within a wrapper "maincontainer" . The wrapper contains a "topsection", a left-floated  "navigation", a "contentcolumn" div to the right and a  fixed position "footer". 
The wrapper "maincontainer" has a background colour and is centralized.

I wish to re-size the "maincontainer" to the height contentcolumns + 140px in case scrolling is required. based on my limited knowledge, I am using a JS code (below). However if I put any images in "contentcolumn", the "maincontainer" remains short and  "contentcolumn" overshoots the    "maincontainer".
I seek help on correcting this behavior.

Thanks

Vivek

Full Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/AuURL/

resize.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var maincontainer_height=document.getElementById('contentcolumn').clientHeight + 140;
 $("#maincontainer").css("height",maincontainer_height + "px");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(function() {
 var maincontainer_height=document.getElementById('contentcolumn').clientHeight + 140;
 $("#maincontainer").css("height",maincontainer_height + "px");
});
});
```